# How to explain the reason of harmonic approximation by Wilson RG?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, renormalization, hamiltonian, many-body, effective-field-theory

It's a part of my homework.

In many body physics, considering the hamiltonian of the ions, we often use harmonic approximation then the hamiltonian turns to
$$
H=\sum_{k}\hbar\omega(b^\dagger b+\frac12)
$$
or
$$
H=\sum_k\frac12\left[\Pi^*(\vec k)\Pi(\vec k)+\omega^2\phi^*(\vec k)\phi(\vec k)\right]
$$
But in high temperatures, the harmonic approximation isn't correct.

So, by using the Wilson RG method, how do we explain the reason for harmonic approximation in low temperature or low energy?

I tried to add the interaction of the phonons into the Hamiltonian, like (I guess, probably not correct)
$$
gb^\dagger(\vec k_1)b^\dagger(\vec k_2)b(\vec k_3)
$$

With $\vec k_3=\vec k_1+\vec k_2$

And follow the Wilson RG methods, turn $\displaystyle\sum_K$ into $\displaystyle\int_0^\lambda$, and integrate the higher part to find the relationship of the parameters of the effect Hamiltonian $H_{eff}$ and the origin Hamiltonian.

But I failed to get a final answer. Is there any mistake in this process, or do I need to try it again in another way?

The biggest question and the reason for simply adding the interaction term is that canonical quantization is too difficult without harmonic approximation.

Comment: You say that it is a homework problem, did the question make any comment about the fact that this additional interaction is non-Hermitian? What about the necessary conservation laws?

Comment: @Alex Chen, The cubic term becomes irrelevant under RG, leading to a free theory. One should check the behavior of the cubic term under scaling. Did you try that?

Comment: @Mass, thx! I will try that later, but I am still not sure about just adding high-order terms into Hamiltonian rather than canonical quantization form the classical Hamiltonian. Just like I said above. the form of the Hamiltonian is from harmonic approximation.

Comment: Please write down the full Hamiltonian, also the dimension of the space. That that put things into the right perspective.